# With Power Query, how to limit Exchange data source to a specific email folder

Tags: excel, powerquery

What I am looking for is a way to limit the scope of the query. Getting all the account then navigating to mail and filtering on what I need isn't a issue. The issue is that doing it pulls over 28 000 emails for nothing.

Here is the beginning of the M code :

```
let
    Source = Exchange.Contents("myMail@myCompany.be"),
    Mail1 = Source{[Name="Mail"]}[Data],
    #"Other Column deleted" = Table.SelectColumns(Mail1,{"Id", "Body", "Categories", "DateTimeSent"}), 
    ...
```

Any idea is welcomed.

Comment: I don't think you can, other then filtering after retrieval  = Table.SelectRows(Mail1, each ([Folder Path] = "\Inbox\foldername\"))

Comment: That's what I feared. I think I read somewhere that there was no way to edit those type of queries before they are sent but I can't find it anymore so I still have hope.